# Is it possible to force mark success any task in a DAG after certain time interval programmatically in Airflow?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I have a DAG with one task that fetches the data from the API. I want that task to fetch the data only for certain time interval and marks itself as SUCCESS so that the tasks after that starts running.

Please note that the tasks below are dependent on the tasks which I want to mark SUCCESS. I know I can mark the task SUCCESS manually from CLI or UI but I want to do it automatically.

Is it possible to do that programmatically using python in Airflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set status of task using python code, like this:

```
def set_task_status(**kwargs):
  execution_date = kwargs['execution_date']
  ti = TaskInstance(HiveOperatorTest, execution_date)
  ti.set_state(State.SUCCESS)
```